# Some tableWidget cells aren't showing in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, openpyxl

So I am creating a tableWidget to track sales in PyQt5 .

[image: Image Of The TableWidget]

The table gets data from an excel sheet .

The problem is that the first two items is showing but the other ones are not ( as you see in the picture )

Here's the code I wrote :

```
def refreshTable():
    ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for j in range(1,ws2.max_row+1):
        ui.tableWidget.insertRow(ui.tableWidget.rowCount())
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(j-1 , 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(ws2["A"+str(j)].value))
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(j-1 , 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(ws2["B"+str(j)].value))
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(j-1 , 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(ws2["C"+str(j)].value))
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(j-1 , 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(ws2["D"+str(j)].value))
```

Note : the excel sheet (ws2) is contains all the necessary information so there is no problem in it.
Note 2 : You may need to know that I'm using openpyxl to read/write in the excel sheet .

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem !

I just put `ws2["A"+str(j)].value` inside `str()`

```
def refreshTable():
    ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for j in range(1,ws2.max_row+1):
        ui.tableWidget.insertRow(ui.tableWidget.rowCount())
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(j-1 , 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ws2["A"+str(j)].value)))
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(j-1 , 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ws2["B"+str(j)].value)))
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(j-1 , 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ws2["C"+str(j)].value)))
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(j-1 , 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ws2["D"+str(j)].value)))
```